# Attach Images to new points when within a Portal for ArcGIS Web App

Tags: arcgis-portal, attachments

I am currently creating an application within Portal for ArcGIS with the aim of allowing users to add point data location and attach images to the newly added point data.

Currently. within this App I have an editable feature layer filled with points. When in the App I am able add points to the layer, and I am able to edit the attribute data, however, I would like the user to be able to attach an image to the point being added.

Does anyone know how to do this?

When in the Map Editor view I am able to attach images to new points, however, I would like this functionality within the Web App itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had a similar issue a few days ago, when you are on the detail page of your feature layer, enable the attachments for the layer of your need.

It looks like this (in my case, it's already enabled): [image]